# Svelte and chartjs, pass data

Tags: chart.js, svelte

I'm trying to create a chart with chart.js and svelte. I call the data in 3 ways and only one works and it's not the one I'm interested in.
In test 1 I have the data in an external js and it works. (data)
In test 2 I put the same array in the svelte file and it doesn't work. (data2)
In test 3 I take the data from an api and configure the array to have the same format as the previous ones. It doesn't work (data_chart)
I need to make the 3rd option work. Any idea why it doesn't like it?

```
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
    import { data } from './data.js';
    import { Line } from 'svelte-chartjs'
    import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, LineElement, LinearScale, PointElement, CategoryScale } from 'chart.js';

    ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, LineElement, LinearScale, PointElement, CategoryScale);

    export let param = String($page.params.slug);

    let ruta_api = `${import.meta.env.VITE_WP_API}posts?slug=${param}`;
    let ruta_api_chart = '';
    let value = [];
    let value_chart = [];
    let data_chart = new Array;
    let id_chart = [];

    const data2 = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'My First dataset',
        borderColor: 'rgb(205, 130, 158)',
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      },
      {
        label: 'My Second dataset',
        borderColor: 'rgb(35, 26, 136)',
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],
      },
    ],
  };  

    onMount(async () => {
        await loadData();
    });

    async function loadData() {
        const response = await fetch(ruta_api);
        const newData = await response.json();
        value = [...value, ...newData];
        ifChart();
    }

    async function ifChart(){
        //comprobamos si viene una grafica en el contenido
        let posicion_chart = value[0].content.rendered.indexOf('m-chart-container-');

        if(posicion_chart >= 0){
            const regex = /(?<=m-chart-container-)(.*?)(?=-)/mg;
            id_chart = value[0].content.rendered.match(regex);

            //recorremos los ids
            id_chart.forEach(function(id) {
                getChart(id);
            })
        }
    };

    export async function getChart(id){
        ruta_api_chart = `${import.meta.env.VITE_WP_API}m-chart/` + id;
        const response_chart = await fetch(ruta_api_chart);
        const newData_chart = await response_chart.json();
        value_chart = newData_chart['m-chart'];

        data_chart = {'labels' : value_chart['data'][0][0], 'datasets': {'label' : value_chart['x_title'], 'data' : value_chart['data'][0][1]}};
    };

</script>

<Line {data} options={{ responsive: true }} />

<Line {data2} options={{ responsive: true }} />

<Line {data_chart} options={{ responsive: true }} />
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be because in

```
<Line {data} options={{ responsive: true }} />
```

`{data}` is the shorthand for `data={data}`
In the other cases the variable name is different, so try changing to

```
<Line data={data2} options={{ responsive: true }} />

<Line data={data_chart} options={{ responsive: true }} />
```

Comment: the second one worked with what you said, the third one didn't, but it must be the fault of the array. Thank you very much